# SSH prompt in Ansible network module development

Tags: ansible

I'm developing a new ansible network module that uses SSH for communication.
That works for simple request-response commands, but that do not works if the device asks for prompt and needs an answer.
How could I modify the code? Or maby where can I look for an example?

Code for running the ssh command is:

```
def run_commands(module, commands, check_rc=True):
    responses = list()
    
    for cmd in commands:
        cmd = module.jsonify(cmd)
        connection = Connection(module._socket_path)
        try:
            out = connection.exec_command(cmd)
        except ConnectionError as exc:
            code = getattr(exc, 'code', 1)
            message = getattr(exc, 'err', exc)
            rc, out, err =  code, '', to_text(message, errors='surrogate_then_replace')
        rc, out, err =  0, out, ''

        if check_rc and rc != 0:
            module.fail_json(msg=to_text(err, errors='surrogate_or_strict'), rc=rc)
        responses.append(to_text(out, errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
        
    return responses
```

Comment: Why would develop such a tool? What's wrong w the current module?
And have you heard of mitogen?

Comment: There’s no module for this type of device (Dell Powerprotect DD backup storage, former Data Domain). I heard about Mitogen but it is forbidden in my company for some reason. 
I can use raw command modules and I used it before. But now I want do develope a reusable module to be used by my counterparts.